# X-Insta-Forwarded-For Error Instagram API using PHP cURL

Tags: javascript, php, curl, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to make a post to instagram using this api and the POST method of relationships.

Here is the side-server code I'm using:

```php
<?php

$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<user>/relationship";
$ips= (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'])) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] : gethostbyname(gethostname());
$signature = (hash_hmac('sha256', $ips, '<secret>', false));

$join = join('|', array($ips, $signature));

$headerData = array('Accept: application/json');

$headerData[] = 'X-Insta-Forwarded-For: ' .$join;

$fields = array(
        'access_token'       =>      '<access_token>',
        'action'             =>      'follow'
    );

$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
?>
```

AS you can see I have this line commented out:

```
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerData);
```

Because as I know, to POST to instagram using cURL I only need a valid access_token, but Instagram is returning me this error:

```
{"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "error_message": "Invalid header: X-Insta-Forwarded-For is required for this operation"}
```

I understand what this means, but my question is if someone has tried something similar without registering an app on Instagram API and using an external access_token found on internet?

Comment: _"academic purposes only"_ Doesn't matter, if it's illegal it doesn't belong on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access_token you are using belongs to an app that probably has this signed header POST restriction active ("**Enforce signed header**").

Go to https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ to create or manage your apps, click on *Edit* app and then on *Security* tab. You should see the page below. **Enforce signed requests** (the new and better signing method) and **Enforce signed header** (the old one, that will be deprecated on September 1th) are the methods to avoid misuse of stolen access_token.

You can't post anything to Instagram API without **X-Insta-Forwarded-For** if **Enforce signed header** is checked. Just as you can't make a request to API without the **sig** parameter if "**Enforce signed requests**" is checked.

I recommend you learn the [new signed request method](https://instagram.com/developer/secure-api-requests/) observing those [Instagram API secure requests considerations](http://instagram-api.tumblr.com/post/120586735719/instagram-secure-api-requests)

[image: Instagram App Security Tab]